# How to test standalone R scripts which are part of a package using testthat

Tags: r, testthat

I am building a R package, `RE` and I would like to package a standalone script with it to be placed in *RE/exec/wrapper.R*. I have written a test function for *testthat* which works just fine when run from the command line using `devtools::test("RE")`, but fails when run using `devtools::check("RE")`.

The relevant code portion that fails is:

```
cmd <- "Rscript \"C:\\RE\\exec\\wrapper.R\" base print \"{\\\"x\\\": 2}\""
rv <- system(cmd, intern = FALSE, ignore.stderr = FALSE, show.output.on.console = FALSE)
```

When run as part of "test" everything runs fine and `system` returns `0` as it should. When run as part of "check", `system` gives out the error message given below and returns `1`.

```
Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) : cannot open the connection
Calls: local ... eval.parent -> eval -> eval -> eval -> eval -> source -> file
In addition: Warning message:
In file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) : cannot open file 'startup.Rs': No such file or directory
Execution halted
```

I have:

1. Checked that the file exists (it does in both cases)
2. Tried `tryCatch`. No error are caught, and `system` just returns a `1`

This makes me think that it is an issue with `system` and `R CMD CHECK`.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in https://github.com/r-lib/testthat/issues/144 . The environment variable `R_TESTS` must be unset via `Sys.setenv("R_TESTS" = "")` in the top level test script (*package_root/tests/testthat.R*), or `system` will not run correctly when called from `R CMD CHECK`. I am leaving the question up, because it took me several hours of experimenting and searching before stumbling on the answer.